# "property is missing and it is not optional" after trying to write data in post request

Tags: javascript, request, electron

I'm trying to add body data into post request in Electron.js. But data writes in some other property. How to properly write data in request?

```
function tokenRequest() {
  var postData = JSON.stringify({
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
  });
  const tokenRequest = net.request({
    method: 'POST',
    protocol: 'https:',
    hostname: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    path: '/api2/json/access/ticket',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
  });

  tokenRequest.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`);
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in tokenRequest response.');
    });
  });
  tokenRequest.write(postData);
  tokenRequest.end();
}
```

Console output:
[image: console output]

Comment: Okay, after a closer look it seems like the formatting of your data is not accepted by the other side - what service are you POSTing to?

Comment: @leonheess I'm trying to post at proxmox, to access remote machine. In this very function I'm POSTing data with username and password for tocken creation.
If more specifically, request url is following: https://192.168.199.94:8006/api2/json/access/ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Proxmox is only accepting URL-encoded JSON data ([source](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API)) you have to replace your `JSON.stringify()` with [`new URLSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams). Also add `toString()` to `postData` before writing it. Here is the full code:

```js
function tokenRequest() {
  const postData = new URLSearchParams({ // <----
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
  })

  const tokenRequest = net.request({
    method: 'POST',
    protocol: 'https:',
    hostname: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    path: '/api2/json/access/ticket',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  })

  tokenRequest.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
    response.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`))
    response.on('end', () => console.log('No more data in tokenRequest response.'))
  })
 
  tokenRequest.write(postData.toString()) // <----
  tokenRequest.end()
}
```

Comment: Your variant throws an error:
`(node:17740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array.`

But if using with electron-fetch it just returns this: { data: null }

Comment: @MihailVagner Hmmm, kindly try again. I added `toString()` in the third line from the bottom.

Comment: My bad, did not see that. Errors are no longer seen in console, but data is still empty:
`STATUS: 401
HEADERS: {"cache-control":"max-age=0","connection":"close","date":"Wed, 19 May 2021 12:56:45 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","server":"pve-api-daemon/3.0","content-length":"13","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","expires":"Wed, 19 May 2021 12:56:45 GMT"}
BODY: {"data":null}
No more data in tokenRequest response.`

Comment: @MihailVagner I think your initial problem is solved. The server has accepted your POST but has determined you are not authorized - did you double-check your username and password?

Comment: Yes, double-checked. So, as I understood, I need to make firstly request for authorizing at proxmox and only then try connect to remote machine?

Comment: @MihailVagner Unfortunately, I haven't heard of Proxmox before today so I don't really know. You might want to ask a separate question to solve the authorization issue. The issue of this question (post data was incorrectly formatted for Proxmox) is resolved as far as I understand it. For you, that unfortunately only means you went from Error 400 to error 401.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you for your help. Will try resolve my new problem.